# Is it possible to use a getter/setter for the text of a UILabel in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios, mono, xamarin.ios

I have the following code

```
public string QuestionText 
{
get { return txtBox.Text; }
set {txtBox.Text = value; }
}
```

where txtBox is a UILabel and everytime I try to access it via QuestionText I get a Null Reference Exception. Am I able to set and get the text like this?

Comment: Yes if your txtBox is initialized.

Comment: @Reniuz I thought it did this within my designer class?

Comment: Check that it does exist in your designer class - sometimes MonoDevelop doesn't integrate well with Xcode & IBOutlets don't show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `txtBox` will be null until `ViewDidLoad` occurs.

A better solution if you are running into that issue:

```
public string QuestionText { get; set; }

public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
   base.ViewDidLoad();

   txtBox.Text = QuestionText;
}
```

Comment: You may also need to use `ViewWillAppear` instead, if your controller can be viewed more than once.